# Displaying AccountBalance via Geth and Web3

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, react

I am throwing together a sample app. I want to query an address and display its account balance.

In the constructor of my React component, I am querying a random address:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider());

  // TODO: This should be a form input
  // Bittrex Address
  this.address = '0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98'
  this.accountBalance = web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(this.address), 'ether');
}
```

I am running geth with the terminal command:

```
geth --testnet --fast --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

When I output `this.accountBalance.toString()` to the console, it's 0. However, if I output the account balance of a valid address on my local testnet (testrpc), it outputs 100 (default balance).

What am I doing incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `geth --testnet` you are connected to the Ropsten chain.

Balance of the address from your code is actually 0 in this chain. Please, check it in etherscan https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x7a970c5653b72232c9d52f7bcda80fc9fbecb7d3

If you really want to know the balance of this address in mainnet, you should start geth without `--testnet` parameter or you can quickly check it with connection of web3 to [INFURA](https://infura.io/) RPC url: https://mainnet.infura.io/your_access_token

Comment: If I sign up with INFURA, would I then be able to host my app somewhere and point to INFURA without having to download the entire blockchain?

Comment: Actually I just tried it out. Thanks for the link to INFURA - exactly what I was looking for for my next step.